# chrome extension checking if javascript already injected

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am looking for best practice to prevent injection my javascript multiple times.
The background script has code like to insert injected.js

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: {tabId: tab.id},
                files: ['content/injected.js']
            })
```

On stackoverflow + other sites I see two options to prevent multiple injections
1.Based on this [stackoverflow reply from @wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208134/avoid-dynamically-injecting-the-same-script-multiple-times-when-using-chrome-tab/23214784#23214784), injected.js variant 1 is

```
if (window.contentScriptInjected !== true) {
    window.contentScriptInjected = true; // global scope
    const focus_event_listner = () => {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
            if (message.type === "StartTimer") {
                console.log('injected.js: start timer')
            }
        });
        console.log(document.title, ": has now been injected")
    }
    focus_event_listner()
} else {
    console.log(document.title, ": was already injected")
}
```

this code works!!
2.However, somewhere (i cannot find the link), it said better to use typeof. So the injected.js variant 2 is

```
if (typeof focus_event_listner === 'undefined') {
    const focus_event_listner = () => {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
            if (message.type === "StartTimer") {
                console.log('injected.js: start timer')
            }
        });
        console.log(document.title, ": has now been injected")
    }
    focus_event_listner()
} else {
    console.log(document.title, ": was already injected")
}
```

This code does NOT work. The questions are

1. which is better way to do the check for prevention of multiple injection
2. in style 2, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: No, it's a false claim because typeof won't work with `const`. Use the first variant.

Comment: ok, thank you @wOxxOm. Is const the problem? meaning if I use a let injected_check_variable = true, will that be good? (I could not get let to work too)

Comment: @ani a `const` is scoped inside the block where it's declared. The `typeof` check is running _outside_ that block, so the variable will not exist there.

Comment: @robertklep, thank you for reply. tried something on lines: if (typeof focus_event_listner_installed === 'undefined') {....}else {...} let focus_event_listner_installed = false. It gives error "Cannot access 'focus_event_listner_installed' before initialization". Going with wOxxOM's solution